# OnClickListener returns null for ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-constraintlayout

I can't add an OnClicklistener to may Constraint Layout. It always returns null.

I have definded a ComplexButton:

```
public class ComplexButton{

private TextView title;
private TextView subTitle;
private ImageView icon;
private ConstraintLayout clickableArea;

public ComplexButton(ConstraintLayout layout) {
    title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
    subTitle = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textview_button_subtitle);
    icon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageview_button_icon);
    clickableArea = (ConstraintLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.complex_button_clickable_area_new);
}
```

I can set the TextView and ImageView.
But For the clickableArea it returns null.

In my other class I make an Instance of it to set the elemets.

```
    @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.NotOfInterrest, container, false);

    ConstraintLayout complexButtonLayout= (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotspotFinder_new);
    ComplexButton complexButton= new ComplexButton(complexButtonLayout);

    complexButton.setTitle( getString(R.string.tab_find_hotspot) );
    complexButton.setSubtitle( "Browse hotspots on our map" );
    complexButton.setImageResource( R.drawable.show_hotspots_map );


    complexButton.setOnClickListener( new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(getContext(), NotOfInterrest.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

And the XML File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@drawable/complex_button_layout"
android:clickable="true"
android:focusable="false"
android:focusableInTouchMode="false"
android:id="@+id/complex_button_clickable_area_new">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_button_icon"
    android:layout_width="50dp"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.027"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/buy_hotspot_subscription" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageview_right_arrow"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_keyboard_arrow_right_black_48dp" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_title"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textColor="@color/colorPrimary"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_button_icon"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageview_right_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textview_button_subtitle"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:text="TextView"
    android:textSize="16dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
    app:layout_constraintLeft_toRightOf="@+id/imageview_button_icon"
    app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/imageview_right_arrow"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/textview_title"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.0" />
```

As said befor: I can set every image and text.
But for the clickableArea i get null pointer.

For ConstraintLayout I use "compile 'com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.2'" 
Is there a newer version ?

Comment: is complex_button_clickable_area_new an instance of ConstraintLayout?

Comment: post your xml layout

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to find `ConstraintLayout` in side your `ConstraintLayout`

```
//Here layout is already an instance of your ConstraintLayout and you are again finding a ConstraintLayout in that
clickableArea = (ConstraintLayout) layout.findViewById(R.id.complex_button_clickable_area_new);
```

You have already find the ContraintLayout and that you are passing to the Constructor of `ComplexButton` class here

```
ConstraintLayout complexButtonLayout= (ConstraintLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.buttonHotspotFinder_new);
ComplexButton complexButton= new ComplexButton(complexButtonLayout);
```

Do this instead

```
public class ComplexButton {

  private TextView title;
  private TextView subTitle;
  private ImageView icon;
  private ConstraintLayout clickableArea;

  public ComplexButton(ConstraintLayout layout) {
      title = (TextView) layout.findViewById(R.id.textview_title);
      subTitle = (TextView) 
            layout.findViewById(R.id.textview_button_subtitle);
      icon = (ImageView) layout.findViewById(R.id.imageview_button_icon);
      //because layout is your constraint layout
      clickableArea = layout;
  }
}
```